# How to position an image list marker so that the text is vertically centered

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm useing the CSS `list-style-image` property. In CSS, how would I make those 'A' words in the following image aligned to the middle of the check marks?

http://i55.tinypic.com/4pwp42.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better use background for LI elements.

```
li{
  list-style:none;
  height: "the height of your bullet image";
  line-height: "same value as above";
  background:url("bg.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
  padding-left: "the width of your bullet image, or even a little bit more";
}
```